# Pybrain: Custom error/performance functions?

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I have built a simple recurrent neural network that predicts a very noisy signal from a series of 15 inputs (statistical breakdowns of the signal).

From what I can tell in the pybrain source (pybrain\supervised\trainers\backprop.py), the error function is hardcoded in the `_calcDerivs` function as the sum of the squared errors divided by the total targets (MSE). The division happens in the `train` function.

In my case, it is most important that the network predict the direction of signal change over the exact change amount, so I want to penalize the NN when it predicts down but signal moves up and vice-versa. I've been experimenting with passing `_calcDerivs` not only the current target, but also the previous target and outputs, which I use to calculate a weight based on whether or not the target guessed the direction correctly, but the network fails to converge using both rprop and backprop. This whole thing is very hack-y to me.

My question is: Is there a *best* way to modify the default performance function? Is all of the performance function code kept in `_calcDerivs` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I found the source of my problem and a possible solution, albiet not one in PyBrain.

The source of my problem was in the derivative of my custom cost (a.k.a performance, etc) function ... or lack thereof. The cost function being used appears to be:

```
0.5 * (error ** 2) # 1/2 the average square error
```

And the derivative of this is simply:

```
error
```

Since I was implementing a more complex error function with a more complex derivative, and I hadn't changed the hardcoded derivative (wherever it's supposed to go), gradient descent was unable to take reasonable steps down the error gradient.

The solution I found was to use [neurolab](http://code.google.com/p/neurolab/), which makes it much easier to implement custom error functions in a modular way. Although some hacking was needed in the core files, I only needed to change roughly three or four lines of core code. (Specifically I modified `ff_grad_step` in tool.py and the last line of the `Train` class in core.py. I implemented my custom cost function by creating a new function in error.py, and making my network hook into it in net.py.)

I hope this wasn't too specific to my own problem for someone else in a similar situation, but this was a huge pain in the ass for something that can be so critical in learning a Neural Network!